# Monitor an applications web service request and response time

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a java web application with many REST web services running in it. Is there any open source or paid tool to monitor the following items of my web services:

- Web services request and response time.
- Web service request and response json.

It will be also good if I have any tools which basically monitors my complete web services activity. Any suggestions.

Comment: Which framework used to expose REST web services?

Comment: I am using Jersey/JAX-RS. Is there any tool to monitor them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Rest web service request and response json

Have a look
[Jersey - Using Filters](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e706)
& [How to register the filter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/LoggingFilter.html)